# valueerror and settingwithcopywarning errors when writing a function to replace values off of an original data frame

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, data-science

I tried to write a function that would replace values from dataframe automatically. My goal was that when the function finds a 0.0 value in the attribute I specified, It would interpolate it the way I wrote it to. The function is below:

```
def interpolator(attribute):
    rows = newdata[newdata[attribute] == 0.0]
    countries = rows['Country']
    for i in countries:
        countrydata = newdata[newdata['Country'] == i]
        a = countrydata[countrydata[attribute] == 0.0]
        if a['Year'] == 2015:
            pass
        else:
            a = countrydata[attribute].replace({ 0:np.nan})
            b = a.interpolate()
            newdata[newdata['Country'] == i][attribute] = b
```

However, when I tried to run this function, I first got a settingwithcopywarning, and it didn't work. When changed the code to above, it started to give a value error: the truth value is ambiguous. Can someone help me?

ps: newdata is the original data frame I want to replace the value of. attribute parameter was supposed to be the column name.

Comment: Hi, your function is doing to many things, making it hard to debug. The warning you're getting comes from the fact that you can't do if/else statements like you're doing on a dataframe. Also, why are you trying to replace 0 with Nan?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to interpolate 0.0 values. Therefore, I tried to first convert zeros to NaN values and then interpolate.

Comment: Ok. If this can be of any help, I'll post a refactored version of your function, though I can't pretend to fully understand what you're trying to accomplish without the underlying data.

Comment: thank you so much. My data is a world happiness dataset for 5 years, and I tried to write a function that would: find the 0 in a column, individually take the countries that have 0, interpolate the missing data by taking the average of the value a year before and after the 0 for the same country, and replace this interpolated value with the 0 in the data frame. Instead of just replacing the 0 value, I tried to write a function that would replace all values of a country. Sory if I wrote confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor in order to remove the for/loop from the function and split it:

```py
def filter(df, country, col):
    mask = (df["Country"] == country) & (df[col] == 0.0) & (df["Year"] != 2015)
    filtered_df = df.loc[mask, :]
    return filtered_df

def interpolator(filtered_df, original_df, col):
    filtered_df[col].replace(to_replace={0: np.nan}, inplace=True)
    interpolated_values = filtered_df[col].interpolate()
    original_df.loc[original_df["Country"] == country, col] = interpolated_values
```

Then it should be easier to test that, at each step, you get what you're expecting:

```py
for country in newdata.loc[df[col] == 0.0, "Country"].values:
    filtered_df = filter(newdata, country, "col_name")
    if not filtered_df.empty:
        interpolator(filtered_df, newdata, "col_name")
```